# Verbose in Loglevel doesn't exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, logging, entity-framework-core, verbose

I try to write my first demo using EF7.

I have installed  [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console 1.0.0-rc2-final](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/1.0.0-rc2-final)

To log.

But when i try to use the follwoing code:

```
public static void LogToConsole(this DbContext context)
        {
            var contextServices = ((IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>) context).Instance;
            var loggerFactory = contextServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Verbose);
        }
```

I couldn't find the `Verbose` enum !

---

Instead i  get the following :

[image]

Could someone help me to explain what's happened and which one should i use to log ?

Comment: What do you want "to log"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in December, the original log levels [were changed a bit](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/124) to be more consistent with other logging systems. As part of this change, `Verbose` was renamed to `Trace` and moved in severity *below* `Debug`.

As for what log level you should use, it depends a lot on what you want to log and what you expect to see. See the recommendations in the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/logging.html#logging-recommendations); to quote the first three bullet points:

> 1. Log using the correct `LogLevel`. This will allow you to consume and route logging output appropriately based on the importance of the messages.
> 2. Log information that will enable errors to be identified quickly. Avoid logging irrelevant or redundant information.
> 3. Keep log messages concise without sacrificing important information.

To choose the correct log level, you should first familiarize yourself with what they mean. Ordered from lowest severity to highest:

- Trace – For the most detailed messages, containing possibly sensitive information. Should never be enabled in production.
- Debug – For possibly interactive investigation during development; useful for debugging but no real long term value.
- Information – For tracking the flow of the application.
- Warning – For unnormal (but expected) events in the application, including errors and exceptions, which are properly handled and do not impact the application’s execution (but could still be a sign of potential problems).
- Error – For real failures which cause the current activity to fail, leaving the application in a recoverable state though, so other activities will not be impacted.
- Critical – For failures on the application level which leaves the application in a unrecoverable state and impacts further execution.

You can find similar explanations in the [offical documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/logging.html#logging-verbosity-levels) and in the project’s [logging guidelines](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/wiki/Guidelines).

Answer (score 2):

Use `LogLevel.Debug`. The levels got renamed and shuffled around in RC2. See [the announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/124) for more details.